# MySQL error #1005 (Code 150)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I have tried create this table, but nothing I have tried works from FKs.

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_AutSituacao` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Nome` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tb_AutHistorico` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Situacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Data` date NOT NULL,
 `Agente` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Proposta` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `AutHistorico_Situacao` (`Situacao`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

ALTER TABLE `tb_AutHistorico` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `Situacao` ) REFERENCES `sicor`.`tb_AutSituacao` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

I always get "#1005 - Can't create table 'tablename' (errno: 150)". Thanks for help.

Comment: Is `sicor` a valid schema name?  You have: "REFERENCES `sicor`.`tb_AutSituacao` (`id`)" perhaps if you remove `sicor` prefix and change to "REFERENCES `tb_AutSituacao` (`id`)"

Comment: Yes it is, but I will do a try without this. UPDATE: Same error with or without schema name.

Comment: When I add semicolons and remove `sicor.`, [it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce926/1). Not sure if it's relevant, but what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Wiseguy MySQL 5.5.16. What you mean with remove semicolons?

Comment: I just added semicolons at the end of the CREATE statements so that it would all run on sqlfiddle (linked in my previous comment). That's it. I copied your queries, added a semicolon after each CREATE statement, and removed `sicor.`.

Comment: @Wiseguy Tried, but does not work =(

Comment: Immediately after getting the error, use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`.  Under LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR it should explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ perror 150
MySQL error code 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
```

Fix your `FOREIGN KEY` definition.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your foreign key constraint definition (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html - last paragraph for debugging)

When this error occurs, either the definition itself is incorrect (syntax error) OR there is an issue with what is being referenced.  Your syntax is correct, what is references is correct, so it's most likely the schema reference.

I can run the statements fine on my end, but I had to prefix the create table names with the schema name.  Otherwise, MySQL will assume that you are trying to create the table for the database you are currently using.  Please see following modified statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `sicor`.`tb_AutSituacao` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Nome` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `sicor`.`tb_AutHistorico` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Situacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Data` date NOT NULL,
 `Agente` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Proposta` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `AutHistorico_Situacao` (`Situacao`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_Situacao` FOREIGN KEY (`Situacao`) REFERENCES `sicor`.`tb_AutSituacao` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also please note that you do not have to define a constraint after creating the table, instead you can include it in the create definition as shown above.